# Kotlin Reflection: How to know if a Kotlin class is marked with "internal" visibility modifier

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect, kotlinpoet

I'm autogenerating code with KotlinPoet and Auto Service. I didn't find any way to know if an annotated class has "internal" modifier so I can create another class with same modifier. For example:

```
@MyAnnotation
internal class Car
```

So I thought using Kotlin Reflection I would be able to get this information but no luck.

With the annotator processor I'm able to get the KClass but the visibility said "public":
[image]

Any clues on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin reflection is not applicable during annotation processing. Kotlin reflection is for inspecting your code at *runtime*.
However there is a way to parse the metadata out of Kotlin class files, it's called [kotlinx-metadata-jvm](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/kotlinx-metadata/jvm).

To use this in your annotation processor, you'll have to obtain the [`AnnotationMirror`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/AnnotationMirror.html) of the `kotlin.Metadata` annotation. From that mirror, obtain the annotation values and use them to construct the `KotlinClassHeader` as you can see in the examples for kotlinx-metadata-jvm. Once you are there you can use kotlinx-metadata-jvm to extract the flags for your class.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin's `KClass` has the `visibility` property, which can be `KVisibility.INTERNAL`.

Comment: I'm doing that but I see "public" instead of "internal". Code used:
`(classElement as Symbol).type::class.visibility`

Comment: `x.type::class` would return the KClass of `Symbol.type` aka `KClass<com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type>`, which is a public class.
If the processed class is on the classpath, loading the class and then reflecting into the KClass would give you the required information. Otherwise you'd need to somehow parse the `@Metadata` annotation kotlin embeds in all its classes.

Comment: I did that (as you can see in the image preview in the question) but still not able to get that value. I tried parsing metadata but I didn't find it there neither. Am I missing something?

Comment: In the image I see you accessing `.type::class`, this does not do what you think it does. `::class` returns the `KClass` of the type it is called on, so since `.type` returns a `com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type` that is the KClass you're accessing.

Comment: oh man you are totally right. I don't really know how to get the KClass from annotation processing in order to get this info

Comment: Most annotaiton processors allow access to annotations within the code. But I dont think Jetbrains have published an official way to access the embedded metadata yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since `internal` is a [visibility modifier](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html), you should look for something related in the `KClass` API. The following will help you:

```
 /**
 * Visibility of this class, or `null` if its visibility cannot be represented in Kotlin.
 */
@SinceKotlin("1.1")
public val visibility: KVisibility?
```

Used like this: `Car::class.visibility //INTERNAL`

Comment: Same as the other answer, I'm doing that but I'm receiving "public": 
`(classElement as Symbol).type::class.visibility` -> public :S
.
Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fxxQeiXO1fnWCuZx9C0BdvDYEaqHXTZ4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: what is `(classElement as Symbol).type::class` giving you exactly?

Comment: A KClass from the annotation processor. Please see the screenshot: Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fxxQeiXO1fnWCuZx9C0BdvDYEaqHXTZ4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I added the screenshot in the question. `(classElement as Symbol).type::class` is giving me a KClass